# How did Miskito ligatures develop?

Tags: morphology, noun-classes

I'm interested in the use of "ligatures", but I'm most interested in the way the
ligatures and the possessives can use a combined infix-suffix. I don't
understand how such a mixed system could develop. I understand the
progression

> u tla 'house' > utla (u or tla is class marker?)
>
> u a tla 'house (-a- ligature) > watla
>
> u a m tla 'your house (m 2nd person) > wamtla

but I don't understand how you could get mixed classes.

> duri 'boat' > dwarka 'boat (-a- ligature)
>
> duri > dwairka 'my boat'
>
> duri > dwarkam 'your boat'

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miskito_grammar

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the history of the Miskito case, but doubling up on morphology is a known development in the history of language.  Here are two examples from English/Germanic:

1. The English word *child* once had plural *childer* (regularized from
   the original invariant   plural *child*).  Another pluralizer *-en*
   was then added, giving modern *children*
2. In Proto-Germanic, there is a class of verbs called preterite presents.  These were perfective in Proto Indo-European, but reanalyzed as presents in Germanic.  The past tense was then formed by addition of a suffix (cognate with Mod. Engl. *-ed*).  So, the past tense forms of verbs carried two "past" markers -- the original PIE ablaut and the Germanic suffix.

If I had to guess what happened in Miskito, I would say that these words were originally in an infixing class (*duri* ~ **dwari*), and were subsequently reanalyzed as being a suppletive stem in the *-ka* class.  (Suppletion is the operation that occurs when a stem changes form after the addition of a suffix.  An example from Mod. Engl. verb inflection is the alternation between *bleed* and  *bled* (< *bleed + ed*).)  But that analysis is only a guess.

Comment: your (1) is like in German: Kind -> Kinder